# How to add Maven dependencies (e.g. Volley, Gson) in Bazel for an Android project?

Tags: java, android, gson, android-volley, bazel

Right now I am doing like this

```
deps = [
   ":tensorflow_native_libs",
   "//tensorflow/contrib/lite/java:tensorflowlite",
   "@androidsdk//com.android.support:appcompat-v7-25.0.0",
   "@androidsdk//com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0",
   "@androidsdk//com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2"
],
```

inside `android_binary`. But I am getting this error:

> ERROR: /home/abhi/Desktop/Git/SENA-28/tensorflow/SenDetect/BUILD:24:1: //SenDetect:sendetect: invalid label '@androidsdk//com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0' in element 3 of attribute 'deps' in 'android_binary' rule: invalid target name 'volley:1.1.0': target names may not contain ':'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## As of April 2019:

An update: [`rules_jvm_external`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external) is a new ruleset by the Bazel team to fetch and resolve artifacts transitively.

In this case, the WORKSPACE file will contain something like this:

```
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0",
        "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2",
        "com.android.support:design:27.0.2",
        "com.android.support:support_annotations:jar:27.0.2",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com",
        "https://maven.google.com",
    ]
)
```

Then in the BUILD file, you can directly depend on Volley and Gson like this:

```
android_library(
    name = "my_lib",
    srcs = # ...
    deps = [
        "@maven//:com_android_volley_volley",
        "@maven//:com_google_code_gson_gson",
        "@maven//:com_android_support_design",
        "@maven//:com_android_support_support_annotations",
    ],
)
```

## As of May 2018:

Both `gmaven_rules` and `maven_jar` are deprecated. Please do not use them anymore.

From the documentation on [docs.bazel.build](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/android-instrumentation-test.html#maven-dependencies), edited with additional relevant instructions:

### Maven dependencies hosted on Maven Central Repository

> Use the [`maven_jar`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#maven_jar) repository rule for Maven dependencies not hosted on
>   Google Maven. For example, to use Volley 1.1.0 and Gson 2.6.2, add the
>   following lines to the `WORKSPACE` file at the top level of the project directory:
>
> ```
> maven_jar(
>     name = "com_android_volley_volley",
>     artifact = "com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0",
> )
>
> maven_jar(
>     name = "com_google_code_gson",
>     artifact = "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2",
> )
> ```
>
> Then, you can depend on them in your `BUILD` files:
>
> ```
> android_library(
>     name = "my_app_lib",
>     srcs = [..],
>     deps = [
>         "@com_android_volley_volley//jar",
>         "@com_google_code_gson//jar",
>     ],
> )
> ```

Note that `maven_jar` is *not* transitive, so it does not download the dependencies of the specified jar. You will need to manually specify additional `maven_jar` rules for the transitive dependencies, or use a tool like [`bazel-deps`](https://github.com/johnynek/bazel-deps) to generate them automatically.

### Maven dependencies hosted on Google Maven Repository (https://maven.google.com)

> For dependencies hosted on [Google's Maven repository](https://maven.google.com/),
>   [`@gmaven_rules`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/gmaven_rules) provides a simple way to fetch dependencies
>   hosted with `gmaven_artifact` by specifying the artifact coordinate directly.
>
> To use `@gmaven_rules`, add these lines to the `WORKSPACE` file:
>
> ```
> # Google Maven Repository
> GMAVEN_TAG = "20180513-1"    
> http_archive(
>     name = "gmaven_rules",
>     strip_prefix = "gmaven_rules-%s" % GMAVEN_TAG,
>     url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/gmaven_rules/archive/%s.tar.gz" % GMAVEN_TAG,
> )
> load("@gmaven_rules//:gmaven.bzl", "gmaven_rules")
> gmaven_rules()
> ```
>
> Then, load the `gmaven_artifact` macro at the beginning of your BUILD file
>   to use it:
>
> ```
> load("@gmaven_rules//:defs.bzl", "gmaven_artifact")
>
> android_library(
>     name = "my_app_lib",
>     srcs = glob(["java/**/*.java"]),
>     deps = [
>         gmaven_artifact("com.android.support:design:aar:27.0.2"),
>         gmaven_artifact("com.android.support:support_annotations:jar:27.0.2"),
>     ]
>     # ...
> )
> ```

Unlike `maven_jar`, `gmaven_artifact` *is* transitive, so you only need to specify the coordinate of the artifact and `@gmaven_rules` will resolve the dependencies automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a lifesaver :)

Comment: @Jin I get `Failed to load Starlark extension '@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl'.` error with bazel 0.25. What am I missing ?

Comment: @expert Please open an issue on the rules_jvm_external GitHub repository with more details.

Comment: How do I use the library in my `.java` file? it says `not found`